# codeigniter htaccess not loaded?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, config

htaccess I have made is not running as it should, why ?

there is my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
php_value memory_limit "64M" 
</IfModule>
```

and the index page config

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

but there is still 404 page not found

```
http://hostname/blog <=== 404 page not found
http://hostname/index.php/blog <=== normal page show up
```

Comment: there is a "#" comment marker in front of your rewrite rule line. why?

Comment: Remove # or try RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]

Comment: get that forward slash out of there^ index.php?/$1 = index.php?$1

Comment: See:  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

should be:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html and the section titled 'Removing the index.php file' You need to use the same RewriteRule, the RewriteConds you have are fine though.

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
    php_value memory_limit "64M" 
    </IfModule>

i have changed my htaccess still 404 page not found :(

Comment: Remove the IfModule tags just to make sure mod_rewrite is even enabled on server.

Comment: Also just to be on the safe side, put some random junk text like dghdkhgksdhkg in the file and save. If it does not error with a 500 server error then your htaccess file is not even being read.

Answer (score 0):

Have the.htaccess file in the application root directory, along with the index.php file. (Check if the htaccess extension is correct , Bz htaccess.txt did not work for me.)

And Add the following rules to .htaccess file,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Then find the following line in your application/config/config.php file

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Set the variable empty as below.

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

That's it, it worked for me.

If it doesn't work further try to replace following variable with these parameters  ('AUTO', 'PATH_INFO', 'QUERY_STRING', 'REQUEST_URI', and 'ORIG_PATH_INFO') one by one

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This is standard content written in [Codeigniter's user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) for removing index.php file, you can add your additional rules in it.